# Ubuntu Installation

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I was installing 32-bit Ubuntu(ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso) on my IBM Thinkpad T510 laptop. During installation an error came up with the following text.

```
(initramfs) mount: mounting dev/loop0 on //filesystem.squashfs failed: Input/Output error Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs) on //filesystem.squashfs
```

I did a memory test which was successful, but when selecting "Try Ubuntu without installing", "Install Ubuntu" or "Check disk for defects" the same error is showing up.

Please help.

Comment: did you check that iso image was properly downloaded and burned to cd?

Comment: Please don't [crosspost between Stack Exchange sites](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5996/unable-to-mount-dev-loop0-during-install), especially without notice, as it needlessly duplicates effort for answerers.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a bad download, check for the MD5 sum using [WinMD5 Sum](http://www.nullriver.com/index/products/winmd5sum) and compare it against the [MD5sums listed:](http://releases.ubuntu.com/10.10/MD5SUMS)

```
a8d8e24bf8b82b4302d074fcac380d65 *ubuntu-10.10-alternate-amd64.iso
419ad8ee1bb76a49490f4a08b5be43f0 *ubuntu-10.10-alternate-i386.iso
1b9df87e588451d2ca4643a036020410 *ubuntu-10.10-desktop-amd64.iso
59d15a16ce90c8ee97fa7c211b7673a8 *ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso
6877bf8d673b87ba9500b0ff879091d0 *ubuntu-10.10-netbook-i386.iso
ab66a1d59a8d78e9ea8ef9b021d6574a *ubuntu-10.10-server-amd64.iso
ce1cee108de737d7492e37069eed538e *ubuntu-10.10-server-i386.iso
d1db1f93bb7486593b7d1ea023c0e3f8 *wubi.exe
```

If the MD5 sums don't match, you'll have to redownload

Answer (score 2):

Might be a problem with either the image or the burn. Verify the checksum of the image, or try a lower burn speed.

Comment: I download the ISO image from Ubuntu website "http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download" here i couldn't   find any checksum information. I was able to mount the ISO image from windows and browse the contents.

Comment: I am installing Ubuntu inside VMWare Workstation 7.1

Comment: A little poking around found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: The ISO image is mounted to a virtual drive in VMWare and not burned on to a CD.

Comment: Although you directly downloaded it from the website... error still occur.  It happens pretty regularly, at least for me.  Check the checksum, or simply redownload the file